# How to use Conditional Formatting in Excel to highlight when both columns are duplicate?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on creating a line card, but it is a group project so I want to confirm that there are no duplicates.
Column A holds a Product Type, selected out of a drop-down list.
Column B holds a Supplier Name, also selected out of a drop-down list.

Over time, we'll try to assign more product types to more suppliers, but I don't want the same product type listed to the same supplier more than once.

For example, in Column A, it will list "Hard Hats", and in Column B, it will match to "Honeywell", and "Pyramex".

How can I use conditional formatting to highlight IF someone tries to enter Hard Hats for Honeywell on another row?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use following formula in conditional formatting rule:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$15,$A1,$B$1:$B$15,$B1)>1
```

[image]